# First Load JS on Parallel routes, how to read them?

Tags: next.js

How should you read the build output on parallel routes?

I have a dashboard that I have splited from RSC/Supense to utilize the power of parallel routes. But I have a hard time understandting the output, because first of all of them say /Overview. But that is easy to figure out that each @route should reprecent each row.
But the FirstLoadJS.. are it shared? Or is that JS dublicated? Please help me understand..

[image]